# Parametric plot intersection

Tags: visualization, parametric-functions

```
l1 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 1}, {2, 1}}]];
l2 = Graphics[Line[{{subDiv, 0}, {subDiv, 2 subDiv}}]];
dotl3 = Graphics[{Dashed, 
                  Line[{{0, subDiv/2}, {2 subDiv, subDiv/2}}]}];
dotl4 = Graphics[{Dashed, 
                  Line[{{0, 3*(subDiv/2)}, {2 subDiv, 3*(subDiv/2)}}]}];
dotl5 = Graphics[{Dashed, 
                  Line[{{subDiv/2, 0}, {subDiv/2, 2 subDiv}}]}];
dotl7 = Graphics[{Dashed, 
                  Line[{{3*(subDiv/2), 0}, {3*(subDiv/2), 2 subDiv}}]}];
circ1 = Graphics[Circle[{subDiv/2, subDiv/2}, .4]];
circ2 = Graphics[Circle[{3*(subDiv/2), 3*(subDiv/2)}, .4]];
fullFigure = Show[l1, l2, dotl3, dotl4, dotl5, dotl7]

xde[x_] := (Sin[x]*.5) + subDiv/2;
yde[x_] := (Cos[x]*.5) + subDiv/2; 
xde2[x_] := (Sin[x]*.5) + 3*subDiv/2;
yde2[x_] := (Cos[x]*.5) + 3*subDiv/2;

animateCircle = 
  Manipulate[
    Show[{ParametricPlot[{xde[t], yde[t]}, {t, 0, 10}], 
          ParametricPlot[{xde2[t], yde2[t]}, {t, 0, 10}], 
          Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.05], Point[{yde[s1*T], xde[s1*T]}]}], 
          Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.05], 
                    Point[{yde2[s2*T - w], xde2[s2*T - w]}]}],
          p1 = ParametricPlot[{yde[s1*T], t}, {t, xde[s1*T], 2}, 
                               PlotStyle -> Red], 
          p2 = ParametricPlot[{t, xde2[s2*T - w]}, {t, -.1, yde2[s2*T - w]},
                                PlotStyle -> Red],
          Show[fullFigure]}, 
      PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False
    ],
   {T, 0, 10 Pi}, {w, 0, -2 Pi}, {s1, 1, 5}, {s2, 1, 5}
  ]
```

How do I solve for the point created by the intersected two red lines?

Answer (score 4):

You need to define `subDiv`. Then the intersection of the red lines is the point `{yde[s1*T], xde2[s2*T-w]}`

```
subDiv = 1;

gr = Graphics[{
    Line[{{0, 1}, {2, 1}}],
    Line[{{subDiv, 0}, {subDiv, 2 subDiv}}],
    Dashed,
    Line[{{0, subDiv/2}, {2 subDiv, subDiv/2}}], 
    Line[{{0, 3*subDiv/2}, {2 subDiv, 3*subDiv/2}}], 
    Line[{{subDiv/2, 0}, {subDiv/2, 2 subDiv}}], 
    Line[{{3*(subDiv/2), 0}, {3*(subDiv/2), 2 subDiv}}]}];

xde[x_] := Sin[x]/2 + subDiv/2;
yde[x_] := Cos[x]/2 + subDiv/2;
xde2[x_] := Sin[x]/2 + 3*subDiv/2;
yde2[x_] := Cos[x]/2 + 3*subDiv/2;

animateCircle = Manipulate[
  Show[{
    ParametricPlot[{
      {xde[t], yde[t]},
      {xde2[t], yde2[t]}}, {t, 0, 10}], 
    Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.05], Point[{yde[s1*T], xde[s1*T]}], 
      Point[{yde2[s2*T - w], xde2[s2*T - w]}],
      Blue,
      Point[{yde[s1*T], xde2[s2*T - w]}]}], 
    p1 = ParametricPlot[{yde[s1*T], t}, {t, xde[s1*T], 2}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
    p2 = ParametricPlot[{t, xde2[s2*T - w]}, {t, -.1, yde2[s2*T - w]}, 
      PlotStyle -> Red], gr}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False],
  {T, 0, 10 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {w, 0, -2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {s1, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {s2, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]